# current datetime in QString?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

so far im using:

```
QTime time = QTime::currentTime();
QString formattedTime = time.toString("hh:mm:ss");
QByteArray formattedTimeMsg = formattedTime.toLocal8Bit();
```

how do i change this to have date and time as "DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss"?

Comment: Have you looked at [`QDateTime`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
QDateTime date = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
QString formattedTime = date.toString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
QByteArray formattedTimeMsg = formattedTime.toLocal8Bit();

qDebug() << "Date:"+formattedTime;
```

You can find more details here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html